# JQuery redirect doesn't work really good

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a the following problem. I have a jQuery script which loads with Ajax every second a page. When the response is "go" he should redirect to a other page. This works only, when he directly gets "go" as response. If the response is first something other and then "go", it doesn't work. Why?

Here my code:

```
      setInterval(function() {
      $("#reset").load('game/gamehandler.php');
      var data = $('#reset').html();
      if(data[0]+data[1] == 'go'){
        $('#answer').modal('hide');
        alert('Du kannst spielen!');
        var url = "http://www.guido-muehlwitz.de";
        $(location).attr('href',url);
      }
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: Cause you are not matching against anything except exactly the word "go". You might wanna use indexOf to check if go is in a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: try to redirect using window.location.href=url

Comment: Try to move the code after the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function into its callback: http://jsfiddle.net/sLBgY/2/ (example)

Comment: What you you mean exactly with "response is first something other and then 'go'"? Also why are you using `.load()`? A "normal" `.ajax()` or `.get()` seems to make more sense here.

Comment: One more thing: All ajax requests (including `load` are asynchron. When you do `$('#reset').html()` the load most likely hasn't finished executing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of this

```
 if(data[0]+data[1] == 'go'){
```

Try These:

```
if (data.indexOf("go") >= 0){

Note that this is case-sensitive.
If you want a case-insensitive search, you can write

if (data.toLowerCase().indexOf("go") >= 0){
Or,

if (/go/i.test(data)){
```